# Understanding Dependent Types

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> sealed trait Parent 
defined trait Parent

scala> case object Boy extends Parent
defined object Boy

scala> case object Girl extends Parent
defined object Girl

scala> trait F {
     |  type A 
     |  def x: A
     | }
defined trait F

scala> case object FImpl extends F {
     |  override type A = Parent
     |  def x: Parent = Boy
     | }
defined object FImpl
```

I then defined a method:

```
scala> def foobar(f: F)(matcher: f.A => Boolean): Boolean = 
     |   matcher(f.x)
foobar: (f: F)(matcher: f.A => Boolean)Boolean

scala> foobar(FImpl)(_ match { case Boy => true; case Girl => false})
res3: Boolean = true
```

I'm confused as to how this works. The compiler must know `f.A`'s type at compile-time then?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Do you expect this not to compile?

Comment: @m-z - Owen captured my unclear question well - `How can the compiler see the member f.A when f is a runtime value?`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is basically: How can the compiler see the member `f.A` when `f` is a runtime value? The answer is that it doesn't. Syntactically, `f.A` looks like it is accessing a member of `f`, but in fact it is relying only on the type of `f`.

When you write:

```
object FImpl extends F {
  override type A = Parent
  def x: Parent = Boy
}
```

`FImpl` defines a new singleton type, known as `FImpl.type`. So, `FImpl.type#A` is `Parent`.

When you call `foobar`, `f.type` is identified with `FImpl.type`, so `f.A` aka `f.type#A` is `FImpl.type#A` aka `Parent`.

Consider these two examples:

```
def needsParent(p: Parent) = ???
def foobar(f: F)(matcher: f.A => Boolean) = ???

foobar(FImpl)(needsParent) // Works
foobar(FImpl: F)(needsParent) // Does not work
```

Although the runtime values are the same, the types differ, and so the compiler accepts one and rejects the other.

In other words, Scala's dependent types are a clever fiction -- in fact, types never depend on actual runtime values. But it turns out that just by identifying types with other types, it becomes possible to keep track of values to a limited extent, giving the impression of types that depend on values.